# How do I resolve error: objectnotfound, difftime() function in R Language

Tags: r, function, object, error-handling, difftime

I have two columns `ended_at` and `started_at`. I want to calculate the time difference  using this code below

`all_trips <- Dfftime(all-trips&ended_at, all_trips&started_at)` but it keeps returning

> object ended_at not found

Comment: Assuming your data frame is named `all_trips`, use `$` instead of `&`: `difftime(time1 = all_trips$ended_at, time2 = all_trips$started_at)`. There are multiple typos in your brief and non-reproducible Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Like most other programming languages (not all), R is sensitive to case and changed characters in object names and functions, and there are several typos in this code: `Dfftime(.)` -> `difftime(.)` (inferred, cannot find your function anywhere); `all-trips` -> `all_trips`. Also, Friede's comment about `&` -> `$` is spot-on; the use of `&` is for the vectorized logical "AND" function. This question is likely to be closed soon ("not reproducible or was caused by a typo"), if our assumptions are incorrect, please [edit] your question to remedy what we should not be trying to correct. Thanks!

Comment: To explain _this_ error, based on the order of operations (see [`?Syntax`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html)) and what `&` means (see [`?&`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Logic.html)), the `-` and `&` operators in the first inner expression suggest that `all`, `trips`, and `ended_at` are separate objects, and it tries to resolve `ended_at` as a visible object. R does not know to look inside of the object `all_trips` to find it (most functions will not); had that succeeded for some reason, you'd get the same error for `trips`.

Answer (score 0):

```
output <- difftime(all_trips$ended_at, all_trips$started_at)
```